# GNOME image viewer can't open jpg file

Tags: files, gnome

I tried to open some .jpg images sent to me on Centos 7 with Gnome Image Viewer (they opened without problems on my Macbook). It gave the following error:

> Error: Could not load image 'image-name.jpg' - Error interpreting image file >(not a JPEG-file starts with 0x89 0x50)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by going in terminal and typing:

```
file /directory/image-name.jpg
```

It appeared to be a .png image file — changing its extension to .png solved it.
Apparently my Macbook automatically detects and solves this.